# System.PlatformNotSupportedException in .NET Core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm trying to compile an application made in .NET Core 2.0 but every time I try to login the post method throws the following error:

```
System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Operation is not supported on this platform.
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeISerializable(JsonWriter writer, ISerializable value, JsonISerializableContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.JsonOutputFormatter.WriteObject(TextWriter writer, Object value)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.JsonOutputFormatter.WriteResponseBodyAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext context, Encoding selectedEncoding)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultAsync(IActionResult result)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResultFilterAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Webpack.ConditionalProxyMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Webpack.ConditionalProxyMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Could you guys help me to fix this error? I found out that multiple modifications were made in .NET Core 2.0 and maybe it doesn't support this method anymore, but it worked before.
Is there anything that can be done to get it working again?

**UPDATE**

I added the code where the error is thrown, it happens when the Ok object is returned.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody]AuthRequest itemRequest)
        {
            try
            {
                var result = await _manager.ValidateUserAsync(itemRequest.Email, itemRequest.Password);

                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    var user = await _manager.GetUserAsync(itemRequest.Email);                  

                    return Ok(new
                    {
                        name = user.name,
                        administrator = user.administrator,
                        permissions = _manager.GetUserPermissions(user.Email)
                    });
                }

                return Unauthorized();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return StatusCode(500);
            }
        }

  public async Task<IEnumerable<Permission>> GetUserPermissions(string value)
        {
            IEnumerable<Permission> permissions;

            using (var connection = GetConnection())
            {
                var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
                parameters.Add("@email", value);

                permissions = await connection.QueryAsync<Permission>("[dbo].[GetUserPermissions]", parameters, null, null, CommandType.StoredProcedure);
            }

            return permissions;
        }

 public class Permission
    {
        public int module { get; set; }
        public bool permission { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: It worked before means you where using a different Framework version and migrated to Core 2 (even if 7 is current and 2 out of support)? Can you show the class that needs to be serialized here (the return type of the endpoint called)? It sounds a bit as if manual serialization via the ISerializable interface is involved and that behavior might have changed.

Comment: I added my code hope it helps. It worked on my old pc a couple of years ago and now I set it up on a new pc because I need to make some changes and I am getting this error

Comment: What does `_manager.GetUserPermissions(user.Email)` return? My guess is it's something that can't be serialized like that. That's important to include in your question in order to have a [mcve].

Comment: Yes, that line it's the main problem, it can't be serialized but I don't know why it stopped working when I changed my machine.

It's an IEnumerable<Permission> where 

public class Permission
{
    public int module;
    public bool permission;
}

Comment: From the call stack it looks like JSON.NET _thinks_ that it's trying to deserialize something that's `ISerializable`. First I would check whether you're using a version of JSON.NET that's appropriate to use in .NET Core 2.0. Then I'd test whether serializing your object directly in your controller causes the same issue. Maybe your namespacing is set up to use the wrong `Permission` class? Maybe something's not happening how you think it is, and the system is trying to serialize an Exception instead of the Permission?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I managed to make the application work again by installing .Net Core 2.0.9!

Comment: at this point .net core 2.0 is out of support. other readers: consider using a supported version of .net